# It's possible to add a background-color: / background: BLACK (with white text) for a page in an AZW3 ebook?

Tags: calibre, editing

I'm trying to make a page black background with white text but it doesn't work. (AZW3 format)

Any ideas for html code?
I've tried both background and background-color and they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make an AZW3 ebook (or a section of an ebook) to have black background and white text by adding `style="background-color:black;color:white"` to the `<body>` tag of the html file with text inside your AZW3.

The problem is whether your chosen e-reader will *display* the background. For example, the internal Calibre reader will happily show black pages with white text; on the other hand, my Kindle Paperwhite 3 *will not* respect the `background-color` setting on body, but *will* use the `color` parameter, rendering white text on white background and making the book unreadable!

Not ideal, to put it mildly.

To get around this, you can set the background color on a div wrapping the text. The downside is that there will always be a white border around the page, because both Calibre reader and Kindle seems to apply its own page borders and ignore any margin or padding settings on `<body>` or `<html>` tags.

If I *really* wanted to do this, I would set the background and text color on both body and a wrapper div - that way I'd get a nice black pages on compliant e-readers, and black rectangles on Kindle and co.

...and then I'd try to test it on as many e-readers as possible, because Murphy's law is a thing, and any styling that has the potential of rendering the content unreadable will probably do it. ;P